# ¿Se puede leer un codigo de barras mediante un scaner desde un app web en react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

debo hacer que una app escrita en react lea mediante un scaner conectado al Pc el codigo de barra de los productos he buscado pero no encuentro nada que me sirva todo los articulos que encuentor sirven pero usnado la camara y yo necesito que sea posible mediante un scaner, ¿Es esto posible? De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: entiendo que como componente de hardware debe de bastar con tenerlo conectado. la única vez que llegué a trabajar con uno, ya hace varios años, al scanear algo lo pegaba automáticamente en el recuadro de texto donde estuviese posicionado.

Comment: Entiendo que todos los scanners envian un \r\n despues de la lectura, captura el evento onKeypress del input text y es todo, nose como se podria hacer con react érp so es javascript si se puede

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver si se puede con js, se puede con react... es lo mismo...

Comment: @gbianchi aaaaa

Comment: Creo que aquí hay preguntas más importantes que hacerse para una implementación así, como dice @gbianchi React es JS, y es para hacer frontEnd. Yo creo que antes de pensar en la interfaz tendrías que resolver cómo hacer el puente de datos entre la página web y el lector en sí, una vez que los datos puedan ser accesados por tú código en JS, puedes hacerle la interfaz que quieras en React.

Comment: Entiendo pero hay alguna libreria que me permita traer esos datos del lector hasta mi app?

Comment: Coincido con lo que dijo @L.Ronquillo y primero deberías informarte [cómo funciona un lector de código de barras](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lector_de_c%C3%B3digo_de_barras), de preferencia, el que planeas usar.